# How to get current time with milliseconds using "time.h" library (only)?

Tags: c++, c, time, time-t

I need to get the milliseconds as well using only the "time.h" library.

For seconds, this is what I have:

```
time_t now;
time(&now);

printf("seconds since  Jan 1, 1970 %d", now);
```

Comment: Answers to this question mostly depend on what standards you have available... only C... or POSIX and if yes, which version(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<time.h>` or `<ctime>` header files, as specified by the C and C++ standards respectively, does not support subsecond timing.

If you can use C++ and have a C++11 compatible environment, then you can get portable support with the `std::chrono` functionality. There's also a `boost::chrono` that could be used in older versions of C++.

Otherwise, you'll have to go system-specific, with for example `gettimeofday` in Linux/Unix and `SystemTime` in Windows. For other OS's, you need to look up what, if any, time functions there are.

Answer (score 1):

Normally one would use an OS-specific or third-party library function for this (e.g. `clock_gettime` on Linux).  However, if you're desperate and really cannot use any other functions, you could make your program busy-wait and count processor cycles using the `clock()` function in time.h.  This is certainly not a good idea, however--just use one of the many other header files that provide what you need.